# Change Faker Locale in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to specify the Faker locale in the database/factories/ModelFactory.php file ?  Here is my non functioning attempt at doing so >,<

```
$factory->define(App\Flyer::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {

    // What is the correct way of doing this?
    $faker->locale('en_GB'); 

    return [
        'zip' => $faker->postcode,
        'state' => $faker->state,  
    ];
});
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Faker locale can be configured in the `config/app.php` configuration file. Just add the key `faker_locale`.

e.g.: `'faker_locale' => 'fr_FR',`

See also my PR to document that previously undocumented feature: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/4161

Comment: For Laravel >= 5.2 this is the best answer.

Comment: I guess this works when you want a _single_ locale for your entire app.. this is no good when you want to support multi-lingual testing

Comment: You can always get the faker instance from the DI container (app())

Answer (score 25):

**THIS ANSWER IS ONLY VALID FOR LARAVEL <=5.1 OR WHEN YOU WANT TO USE MANY DIFFERENT LOCALES** see [this answer for a solution in Laravel >=5.2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42594893/490961).

To use a locale with Faker, the generator needs creating with the locale.

```
$faker = Faker\Factory::create('fr_FR'); // create a French faker
```

From the faker documentation:

> If no localized provider is found, the factory fallbacks to the default locale (en_EN).

Laravel by default, binds the creation of a faker instance in the `EloquentServiceProvider`. The exact code used to bind is:

```
// FakerFactory is aliased to Faker\Factory
$this->app->singleton(FakerGenerator::class, function () {
    return FakerFactory::create();
});
```

It would appear that Laravel has no way to modify the locale of the faker instance it passes into the factory closures as it does not pass in any arguments to Faker.

As such you would be better served by using your own instance of Faker in the factory method.

```
$localisedFaker = Faker\Factory::create("fr_FR");

$factory->define(App\Flyer::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {

    // Now use the localisedFaker instead of the Faker\Generator
    // passed in to the closure.
    return [
        'zip' => $localisedFaker->postcode,
        'state' => $localisedFaker->state,  
    ];
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure where the EloquentServiceProvider is located but your idea for creating a localised version of faker works great.  Thanks a lot. I edited your code sample to reflect that $localisedFaker needed to be within scope of the factory method as you previously explained.

Comment: It's in the core 'Illuminate\Database\EloquentServiceProvider'. You can't really modify it without a lot of messing around. Best to carry on with the localised version, glad I could help :-)

Comment: Should not be the accepted answer anymore, there is a simple way to do it via configuration file. See my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42594893/490961

Comment: I changed the accepted answer based on David and Vincent's suggestion to https://stackoverflow.com/a/42594893/3951121 despite not having tested Vincent's method.

Answer (score 9):

I prefer to use it:

```
$fakerBR = Faker\Factory::create('pt_BR');

$factory->define(App\Flyer::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) use (fakerBR) {

    return [
        'name'  => $fakerBR->name,
        'cpf'   => $fakerBR->cpf,
        'zip'   => $faker->postcode,
        'state' => $faker->state,  
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Late in the party, but after some research I've found this in faker documentation:

> [...] since Faker starts with the last provider, you can easily override existing formatters: just add a provider containing methods named after the formatters you want to override.
>
> That means that you can easily add your own providers to a Faker\Generator instance.

So you can do something like this

```
$faker->addProvider(new Faker\Provider\pt_BR\Person($faker));
```

Just before `return []` and then use specific providers, like (in this case) `$faker->cpf;`

**Tested on Laravel 5.3**

More info on [Faker documentation](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#faker-internals-understanding-providers)

Answer (score 4):

This answer is valid just for Laravel 5.4 and greater:

Since [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/17895/files) pull, you can just use 'faker_locale' as a variable in your app config file. It just works really good.

Answer (score 3):

@IvanAugustoDB, there is a another form of doing that. When Laravel initalize faker, it can be constructed on another locale, just create a Service Provider and put the following snippet inside it.

```
use Faker\Generator as FakerGenerator;
use Faker\Factory as FakerFactory;


$this->app->singleton(FakerGenerator::class, function () {
    return FakerFactory::create('pt_BR');
});
```

Comment: I acutally had problems with faker in symfony. `Generator` or `DefaultGenerator` were not working. `FakerFactory::create('pt_BR');` helped.

Answer (score 3):

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    $faker->addProvider(new Faker\Provider\ng_NG\Person($faker));
    $faker->addProvider(new Faker\Provider\ng_NG\PhoneNumber($faker));
...
```

in the above code, "ng_NG" is for Nigeria and can be replaced with any other locale.

To my knowledge, you would have to specify Person, PhoneNumber and others depending on what you have in your vendor\fzaninotto\faker\src\Faker\Provider folder. However if the provider you intend using isn't available, then it will resolve back to using "en".

This works like charm for me, and it should work for you too.

Answer (score 1):

this is the link for all [providers](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/tree/master/src/Faker/Provider) that used in faker

for arabic lang example

```
    use Faker\Factory as Faker; ### in the head off class

    $faker = Faker::create();
    $faker_ar = Faker::create('ar_SA');

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        DB::table('categories')->insert([
            'name'          => $faker->name,
            'name_ar'       => $faker_ar->name,
            'created_at'    => now(),
            'updated_at'    => now(),
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple languages for the same table and can't use local
you can use: shuffleString

```
'name'=>$faker->shuffleString('abddefhig')
'name_ar'=>$faker->shuffleString('البتثجحخدزسش')
```